# string is not recognized as html when trying to load it using HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am fighting with this issue all morning. I am getting the result from post request, and compare it to Fiddler result which are identical. However when I load it in `HtmlAgility doc.LoadHtml(str);` the string is not recognized as html, thus i can't parse it. To verify that the above response is correct, I created a string variable and assigned to it the exact above response, et viola it is recognized as Html. I can't find what am I missing.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string data = string.Empty;
StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(Url, queryString, ct);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
```

`doc.Text` is loaded but it is not formatted, thus I can't parse it.

When I assign the `string str` content to the above result:

```
string str = ""\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"media-window\" style=\"position: fixed; left: 25px; top: 25px; right: 25px;\r\n    display: none; bottom: 10px;\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cspan class=\"layer-close\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"close\"\u003eClose\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n"
doc.LoadHtml(str);
```

It is loaded and parsed fine.

Comment: Try `doc.Load` in place of `doc.LoadHtml`.

Comment: If I use Load I am getting Emtpy path name is not legal

Comment: Next I have an Illegal characters in path exception

Comment: Is the Uri you're trying to load from a public one? Is the encoding returned by the webserver UTC-8? You might be having a string encoding issue causing the HtmlAgilityPack to have issues. Try setting the `Accept-Encoding` header on your request or verify the `Response.Content.Headers.Encoding` and if needed tell the `HtmlDocument` which encoding to expect. See also: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/79517

Comment: The Uri Is Ajax responce , and I have replicated the exact headers. So when I have the responce I can verify that it correct, according to fiddler.. Also As described above I am putting the exact responce in string and it is recognized and html....

Answer (score 0):

Asking the right question will give you eventually the right answer:

```
var decodedString = Regex.Unescape(yourString);
```